# Setting S3 Event triggers using EventBridge

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-event-bridge

I have the following nested folder structure.

```
root
  - folder A
     - folder B
          a.png
     - folder C
          b.png
```

I am trying to set a S3 Eventbridge rule that needs to trigger when a ".png" file gets put in the inner folders and the target for the eventbridge rule is a AWS Lambda function.

The questions I have are the following:

```
1. Can EventBridge support wildcards?
2. I created an event rule pattern "*/*.png" that doesn't work
3. Will suffix help in this case?
```

Looking for help on how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using below steps:

- Open your bucket in AWS Console -> properties tab
- Under **Event notifications** , click on create event notification
- Configure your directory (prefix) and extension (suffix, .png in your case) to monitor.
- and choose which operation you want to monitor (Put in your case)

[image: s3 event notification]

- Choose lambda function to trigger
- Save changes

This event will trigger configured lambda function whenever the put operation happens on configured prefixes and suffixes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an event rule pattern like this "**/*.png"